# Error in figure labels in patent US 7,791,591 B2

Tags: error, figure, labels

in patent number US 7,791,591 B2 on "optical mouse using VCSEL"
in fig.1, number 22 seems to refer to two different things: a computer first and than the same number is used for labelling a "light absorbing line"? The description of 20 and 22 is in column 2.

https://patents.google.com/patent/US7791591B2/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. Adding a link to the patent would make it easier for those who might answer. Also can you clarify what your actual question is?

Answer (score 1):

If your question is “is this a mistake” - yes, if your question is “ does it matter” — no. I’m sure this type of error is common.